# Updated a Table "c" with data and this update should again update a column in table "a" and table "b"

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have table C with multiple columns, any update in one of the column of Table C must update the columns from table a and b

the relation b/w table @ db level is none, there is one column which holds some key information in table a and b and nothing else.

Right now i am doing this from a JAVA application but i have millions of records to go loop through is it possible to achieve this in DB itself like inbuilt oracle functionalities...

How do i achieve this, was thinking of triggers but i ppl say its not  good to use trigger.

We tried with java application but looping through millions of records is time consuming

No DB relation b/w table A B and c, except we keep some information of table C's portID in table A and B. i won't be able to change relation in DB level

table C:

```
portID  State 
6001     1 -------> Updated to 2 
6002     1
```

Then

table A:

```
portID  State 
6001     1 -------> after Table C update this should also Updated to 2
```

table B:

```
portID  State 
6001     1 -------> after Table C update this should also Updated to 2
```

**If At all i can change the relation between these tables how do i achieve so that DB can take care of this updating A and B tables ?**

Comment: Why?  Look up the value in `C` so you are not duplicated data in a bunch of tables.

Comment: did this using a java application where whenever an update to tables c you query all the rows with portid x in table a and b but updating large records takes lots of time and is causing performance issue....how to achieve this @ DB level like triggers....

Comment: It is unlikely that a trigger could do anything more efficiently here.  You'd likely have the same performance issues with a trigger.  This is why denormalizing data is a problem-- if you ever try to update it, you have to update it multiple places rather than just one.  Is `portID` indexed in A & B?

Comment: ohh okie.. yes it is indexed column in A and B

Comment: If At all i can change the relation between these tables how do i achieve so that DB can take care of this updating A and B tables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using an `AFTER` trigger in Oracle. I'll give you an example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "trg_upd_tbl_a_tbl_b"
AFTER UPDATE ON c
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD as Old
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF UPDATING THEN
        UPDATE a SET a.state=:New.state WHERE portID=:New.portID;
        UPDATE b SET b.state=:New.state WHERE portID=:New.portID;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: i see lot of people mentioning triggers are not an ideal solution.... and my application contain huge data in millions....do you think triggers will be fine or same as my application where i have a performance issue...

Comment: Triggers are the way to go as the subsequent changes you made to the tables will be wrapped in a single transaction. You can be sure of the data integrity once you have it done this way.

Comment: Thanks....i am bit hesitant to use one... let me explore possible solutions before i implement this triggers as a last resort.